# HOW Go Next in Data GridView

Tags: c#

I have a search form and its result show in Data grid view(DG) at bottom of my form.
after do the search,my sql data loaded to DG.
in the RowHeaderMouseDoubleClik Event of DG,i have a new form show dialog and show information From DG current row.

in this form i need a Next Button,and when clicked,next row information of Dg, shows up in this form.

how can i do this.tanx all

```
 private void GrdSearch_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            z = GrdSearch.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
            x = GrdSearch.CurrentRow.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();
            c = GrdSearch.CurrentRow.Cells["Tel1"].Value.ToString();
            v = GrdSearch.CurrentRow.Cells["owner"].Value.ToString();
            b = GrdSearch.CurrentRow.Cells["LandKind"].Value.ToString();
            n = GrdSearch.CurrentRow.Cells["FileKind"].Value.ToString();
             .....
            FrmShowFromGrd frm = new FrmShowFromGrd();
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

second form:

```
    private void FrmShowFromGrd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxtOwner.Text = FrmSearch.v;
            TxtLandKind.Text = FrmSearch.b;
            TxtTel1.Text = FrmSearch.c;
            TxtFileKind.Text = FrmSearch.n;
            TxtDate.Text = FrmSearch.x;
            TxtId.Text = FrmSearch.z;
        }
```

Comment: You need to use instances of the forms to pass data.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: i am sorry but i dont understand.i have passed GridView data with double mouse click ,To form 2.Now i need a Next button  "in form 2 " to read Next Row information of form1's GridView.Can u exlpain more Please.

Comment: My example code passed the instance of Form1 to Form 2.  Then using the instance form1 (lower case) I can assess data in form 1 or call a method in form 1.

Comment: thank you my friend i understand it.now how tell data grid to show next row from where user double clicked on that.is there an event for that?

Comment: The form that contains the Grid should have a variable call Selected Row (or equivalent).  So create in the same form a method called GetNextRow that increments the Selected row.  Then returns the data in the row.  The Search form should call the GetNextRow to get the data.  The call should be made with the instance of the form.